# How to customize menu in electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have one frameless electron app which can be run on windows and mac system. I have learned how to set ApplicationMenu and contextmenu(right click only). But, I want to set an Image like settings and clicking on that will open the customized menu (which have its HTML, CSS and js) which catch the events like focusedWindow to get the current focusedWindow. How can I achieve this functionality? Below is the image which describes what I am trying to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a div where I am showing and hiding a dive on setting image click. To call browserWindow instance in renderer side you can use remote to call the instance like:

```
 remote.getCurrentWindow().setPosition(x, y);
```